# How to make a video with only a fullscreen button (and no other controls)

Tags: wordpress, video, autoplay

I have a worry with wp video shortcode (for a video on loop and autoplay), which plays fine on firefox, but who doesn't in chrome.

This is my code:

```
<div class="fullscreen-button-only">
[video mp4="https://www.underthedeepdeepsea.com/wp-content/uploads/videos/NUM-still-life.mp4" poster="" muted="true" loop="true" autoplay="true"]
</div>
```

The div here allows to apply a class to the video, with a css which hides all controls except the fullscreen button, which appear when you hover the video.

Usually I would resolve this by using a more classical videotag, like this one:

```
<div class="fullscreen-button-only">
<video src="https://www.underthedeepdeepsea.com/wp-content/uploads/videos/NUM-still-life.mp4" preload="true" autoplay="true" muted="true" loop="true" playsinline width="100%" poster=""></video>
</div>
```

It works on chrome, but it's far more difficult to make appear the fullcscreen button alone on it.

Is there a solution to make the traditional [wp video] shortcode work with loop and autoplay?

---

---

**UPDATE : HERE IS THE SOLUTION** for video with only a full-screen button, with the last fixes needed (thanks to my brother!) added to the great code proposed by VC.One. Here is the code working.

**HTML :**

```
  <div id="animatedgif_1" class="fx_fadeIn" style="position: relative; width: 100%; text-indent: 0px; ">
    <video class="centrer-verticalement" width="100%" style="" muted playsinline loop autoplay>
      <source src="https://www.underthedeepdeepsea.com/wp-content/uploads/videos/NUM-wish.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
    <div id="btn_fs" onclick="go_FullScreen( this )" style="position: absolute;">
      <img id="img_btn_fs" width="40" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI5kS.png">
    </div>
  </div>

  &nbsp;

  <div id="animatedgif_2" class="fx_fadeIn" style="position: relative; width: 100%; text-indent: 0px; padding-bottom:0em !important; ">
    <video class="centrer-verticalement" width="100%" style="" muted playsinline loop autoplay>
      <source src="https://www.underthedeepdeepsea.com/wp-content/uploads/videos/NUM-hobbit-1280crf.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
    <div id="btn_fs" onclick="go_FullScreen( this )" style="position: absolute;">
      <img id="img_btn_fs" width="40" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI5kS.png">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.fx_fadeIn img {
  opacity: 00%;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.fx_fadeIn:hover img {
  opacity: 100%;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.centrer-verticalement[style*="background: transparent"]+#btn_fs img {
  opacity: 20%;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.centrer-verticalement[style*="background: transparent"]+#btn_fs img:hover {
  opacity: 100%;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.fx_fadeIn .centrer-verticalement[class*="background: none"]+#btn_fs img {
  opacity: 0%;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.fx_fadeIn:hover .centrer-verticalement[style*="background: none"]+#btn_fs img {
  opacity: 100%;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

#btn_fs {
  bottom: 1em;
  right: 1em;
}
```

Note that if you put the HTML code on wordpress, it will add a `<p>` after the video tag, which will need an adaptation of a part of the CSS, like that:

```
.centrer-verticalement[style*="background: black"]+p+#btn_fs img {
  opacity: 20%;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.centrer-verticalement[style*="background: black"]+p+#btn_fs img:hover {
  opacity: 100%;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.fx_fadeIn .centrer-verticalement[class*="background: #010101"]+p+#btn_fs img {
  opacity: 0%;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.fx_fadeIn:hover .centrer-verticalement[style*="background: #010101"]+p+#btn_fs img {
  opacity: 100%;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

And finally, you can add this CSS code at the end of all that, if you want the fullscreen icon to always appear for smartphones and ipad :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .fx_fadeIn img {
    opacity: 20% !important
  }
}

@media only screen and (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) {
  .fx_fadeIn img {
    opacity: 20% !important
  }
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT (updated) :**

```
var bool_isFullscreen = false;

//# access DIV that is container for [ video + button image ].
var myVideoGIF; //# = document.getElementById("animatedgif");

//# access DIV that is a click "hotspot" to enter fullscreen.
var myBtn_FS; //# = document.getElementById("btn_fs");

//# access IMG for button that will change mode to fullscreen.
//var img_myBtn_FS; //# = document.getElementById("img_btn_fs");

window.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', on_FS_Change, false);

function on_FS_Change(evt) {
  //######################################
  //# detect event for screen mode change
  //#is "null" when page/element is not in Fullscreen
  if (document.fullscreenElement != null) {
    bool_isFullscreen = true;
  }

  //# assume is already in Fullscreen mode
  else {
    bool_isFullscreen = false;
    exit_FullScreen();
  }

}

function go_FullScreen(input) {
  //# NOTE : child elements are in order of appearance in setup
  //# Parent == DIV as container
  //# children[0] == VIDEO tag is first child element
  //# children[1] == DIV for button icon is second child element




  //##############################################################
  //## Get access to the specific clicked item's Parent (container)
  myVideoGIF = document.getElementById(input.parentNode.id);
  myBtn_FS = myVideoGIF.children[1];



  //########################################
  //## Check if screen mode is : Fullscreen
  //## If already Fullscreen then just do the "on exit fullscreen" code 
  //## then quit (RETURN) from this function (ignores rest of code below)
  if (bool_isFullscreen == true) {
    exit_FullScreen(); //# handle on exit fullscreen
    return; //# quit/exit code here...
  }

  //##############################################################
  //## Will continue onto code below if NOT Fullscreen (no return)

  function openFullscreen(elem) {
    //# for most browsers
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
    }

    //# for Safari (older versions)
    else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }

    //# for Safari (newer versions)
    else if (elem.webkitEnterFullscreen) {
      elem.webkitEnterFullscreen();
    }

    //# for Safari iPhone (where only the Video tag itself can be fullscreen)
    else if (elem.children[0].webkitEnterFullscreen) {
      elem.children[0].webkitEnterFullscreen();
      //toggle_controls(); //# your own function to show/hide iOS media controls
    }

    //# for Internet Explorer 11
    else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
  }

  openFullscreen(myVideoGIF);


  myVideoGIF.children[0].style.width = "100%"
  myVideoGIF.children[0].style.height = "100%"
  myVideoGIF.children[0].style.background = "black"

  //# set to true (helps "exit_FullScreen" function )
  bool_isFullscreen = true;

}

var videoContainer = document.getElementByClassName('fx_fadeIn');
var video = videoContainer.getElementsByTagName('video');

function toggleVideoFullscreen() {

  if (video.webkitEnterFullScreen) {
    // Toggle fullscreen in Safari for iPad
    video.webkitEnterFullScreen();
  } else {
    // Toggle fullscreen for other OS / Devices / Browsers 
  }
}



function exit_FullScreen() {


  if (bool_isFullscreen == true) {
    bool_isFullscreen = false;

    //#########################################
    //# check IF browser can use this method...
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen()
        .then(() => console.log("Document Exited from Full screen mode"))
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));

      myVideoGIF.children[0].style.background = "#010101"

    }

    //## OR ELSE try other browser options

    /* for Safari */
    else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }

    /* for IE11 */
    else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    }
  }

}
```

Here is the full jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TB54/keLy49z8/19/

Finally, note that those multiple videos won't autoplay on Xiaomi Mi browser, but that's another problem not related to the code.

Comment: Is this fixed now? Your page link shows me a player with only the fullscreen button in Chrome.

Comment: Hello! No, nothing has change, I have not found a solution. On my Chrome (version 108.0.5359.125, on PC), I have just the first image of the video still, and no button: https://i.imgur.com/UStPlf8.png

Comment: For me it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyk0l.png . The FS button shows when I move the mouse over the video (if I have moved the mouse away from the video tag, sometimes it doesn't work unless I go to its expected position then it just shows)...

Comment: Ok, that's really weird... It would be because of a difference between Chrome on Mac and Chrome on PC ? Note that it's also stuck for me (the same way) on Edge (I also realize you have black border lines on yours, which i managed to hide on my firefox and chrome...).

Comment: Chrome and Edge are both using same webkit engine so it gives the same browser result. I can't explain the black borders, they are there in Windows Firefox too. Try opening the link in **incognito mode** (in case this a page caching issue). PS: I will write some possible suggestions for you...

Comment: PS: I don't have a Mac to test, so yeah it is worrying that Chrome has different results on two operating system. I've never seen my pages on a Mac (cos I trusted the browsers to just work as expected)...

Comment: OK. Please check and test the options in the Answer box. I should clarify I don't make full web pages per se, I just create specific contents in Javascript (media players or image filters, etc) but still my output is on the page, right. Never seen it on Mac but also never got complaints from Apple users... **PS:** After re-reading the comments I see you're on a PC too. Maybe there's no issues in Mac then, but the new question is why two PC's with Chrome are showing different things from the same link?

Comment: Yes, we're both on PC (i thought Mac on your side, don't know why). It's even weirder. I disabled all my extension, no difference. Is it the same version of Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Usually I would resolve this by using a more classical video tag... But it's far more difficult to make appear the fullscreen button alone on it."*

**Update:**

Here is some example code you can study, then also apply the same logic into your WordPress. 
(*eg:* put Styles/Scripts wherever these Styles/Scripts are put when creating WP articles or pages).

The code below uses an image to create a custom fullscreen button. This **should work in all browsers** because it is just an `<img>` tag inside a `<div>` with a "click" listener.

PS: You can download (and customize) a free fullscreen icon here: [icons8.com](https://icons8.com/icons/set/fullscreen). 
(Another [good site for customized PNG](https://www.svgrepo.com/svg/82051/fullscreen) icons, but you cannot remove their big advert. You must scroll down by a small amount until you see the "Edit Vector" option next to the icon (is at bottom left of icon).

**code example (updated 19/01/2022):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>

/* .fade-in-image { animation: fadeIn 4s; } */

.fx_fadeIn img 
{ opacity: 30%; transition: opacity 2s; }

.fx_fadeIn:hover img 
{
  opacity: 100%;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

</style>

<body>

<div id="animatedgif_1" class="fx_fadeIn" style="position: relative; width: 640px; height: 360px;" >
    <video width="100%" style="position: absolute; top: 0px" muted playsinline loop autoplay><source src="https://www.underthedeepdeepsea.com/wp-content/uploads/videos/NUM-Amandiers4.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></p>
    <div id="btn_fs" onclick="go_FullScreen( this )" style="position: absolute; top: 86%; left: 90%;">
    <img id="img_btn_fs"  width = "40" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI5kS.png" >
    </div>
</div>

<div id="animatedgif_2" class="fx_fadeIn" style="position: relative; width: 640px; height: 360px;" >
    <video width="100%" style="position: absolute; top: 0px" muted playsinline loop autoplay><source src="https://www.underthedeepdeepsea.com/wp-content/uploads/videos/NUM-still-life.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></p>
    <div id="btn_fs" onclick="go_FullScreen( this )" style="position: absolute; top: 86%; left: 90%;">
    <img id="img_btn_fs"  width = "40" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI5kS.png" >
    </div>
</div>


<script>

var bool_isFullscreen = false;

//# access DIV that is container for [ video + button image ].
var myVideoGIF; //# = document.getElementById("animatedgif");

//# access DIV that is a click "hotspot" to enter fullscreen.
var myBtn_FS; //# = document.getElementById("btn_fs");

//# access IMG for button that will change mode to fullscreen.
//var img_myBtn_FS; //# = document.getElementById("img_btn_fs");

window.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', on_FS_Change, false);

function on_FS_Change (evt) 
{
    //######################################
    //# detect event for screen mode change
    //#is "null" when page/element is not in Fullscreen
    if( document.fullscreenElement != null )
    { bool_isFullscreen = true; }
    
    //# assume is already in Fullscreen mode
    else 
    { bool_isFullscreen = false; exit_FullScreen(); }
    
}

function go_FullScreen( input ) 
{
    //# NOTE : child elements are in order of appearance in setup
    //# Parent == DIV as container
    //# children[0] == VIDEO tag is first child element
    //# children[1] == DIV for button icon is second child element
    
    //##############################################################
    //## Get access to the specific clicked item's Parent (container)
    myVideoGIF = document.getElementById( input.parentNode.id );
    myBtn_FS = myVideoGIF.children[1];
    
    //########################################
    //## Check if screen mode is : Fullscreen
    //## If already Fullscreen then just do the "on exit fullscreen" code 
    //## then quit (RETURN) from this function (ignores rest of code below)
    if( bool_isFullscreen == true ) 
    { 
        exit_FullScreen(); //# handle on exit fullscreen
        return; //# quit/exit code here...
    }
    
    //##############################################################
    //## Will continue onto code below if NOT Fullscreen (no return)
    
    myVideoGIF.requestFullscreen();
        
    //#####################
    //## ALIGN -- VERTICAL
    //## Need to subtract : height of screen -minus- height of video
    //## Then divide result by two to get central point
    
    //# find the new fullscreen Width of video object 
    //# by temporay setting to "100w" ("vw" == viewport width)
    myVideoGIF.children[0].style.width = "100vw";
    
    //# formula = ( screen Height - video Height(eg: its clientHeight) ) 
    //# then "Divide by 2" to get the central value from total
    let align_vertical = ((screen.height - myVideoGIF.children[0].clientHeight) / 2); 
    myVideoGIF.children[0].style.top = align_vertical+"px"; //"5%";
    
    //# reset back to 100% width for display inside Div's width
    myVideoGIF.children[0].style.width = "100%";
    
    //# set to true (helps "exit_FullScreen" function )
    bool_isFullscreen = true;
    
}

function exit_FullScreen( ) 
{
    myVideoGIF.children[0].style.top = "0px";
    
    if( bool_isFullscreen == true )
    {
        bool_isFullscreen = false;
        
        //#########################################
        //# check IF browser can use this method...
        if (document.exitFullscreen) 
        { 
            document.exitFullscreen()
            .then(() => console.log("Document Exited from Full screen mode"))
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
        }

        //## OR ELSE try other browser options

        /* for Safari */
        else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { document.webkitExitFullscreen(); }

        /* for IE11 */
        else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { document.msExitFullscreen(); }
    }
    
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Old Answer:**

This is not a final Answer, just a "super" comment for testing advice...

**(1)** Try adding this `<div>` code:

```
<div class="image fullscreen-button-only">
<video muted playsinline loop autoplay>
<source src="https://www.underthedeepdeepsea.com/wp-content/uploads/videos/NUM-still-life.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
```

The result should be your page now has **two** videos (your original one and then also this new Div).
I will check the page for what is happening then advise further if needed...

**(2)** In Chrome you can try the below code to get fullscreen button only.
Note: It won't work in Firefox because it's **Gecko** engine but Chrome/Edge is using **Webkit** engine.
[Copy/Paste shown code here for a quick testing](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>

video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-control-container,
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button,
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline,
video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display,
video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display
{ display: none; }

</style>

<body>

<video width="550" height="310" oncontextmenu="return false;"
playsinline muted autoplay loop
disablepictureinpicture
controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate noremoteplayback ">
<source src="https://www.underthedeepdeepsea.com/wp-content/uploads/videos/NUM-still-life.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Does that work (shows only Fullscreen button) in Chrome on Mac?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I put your code below: it works in my Chrome (in the sense the video loops and autoplays, but the fullscreen button is not there, and the size it wrong but this should be easy to fix).

The second code (if I put it in your testing link) works on Chrome, it autoplays, loops, and I only have the fullscreen button (and black border appears).

Comment: OK I've seen your updated page. I think the best option is to work with that one (lower video tag) by adding a custom FS button there. Basically recreating what the WP short-code itself is doing. Check for an update in 30 mins or so...

Comment: Hello! You meant an update to try another code?

Comment: Sorry for the suspense. I did mean after a 30 minute mission I had to do, but then I got kidnapped by the _"saturday night"_ aliens which led to other things... Anyways I've put a code example that you can use as a starting point. Customize it how you want and ask anything about that code.

Comment: PS: You can also test it as a local html file. Just paste code into Notepad and save as **test.html**. Drag or Open into Chrome.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Don't know if it's a problem in the code, or if it's related to a conflict with other CSS in my wordpress, but there are two problems left: the fullscreen button appears up in the page (i can set a relative position, but hard without knowing how it will be depending on the width of the video (which will depend of screen resolution); and the fullscreen video is not vertically centered. I didn't touch yet to the video size (which is too large for now. it's at the same adress, below video: https://www.underthedeepdeepsea.com/?p=34880&draftsforfriends=0XoeWItadFpuXlBE1ziXptDNcMwHaHRg

Comment: Ok, I have the result i would like by removing the width/height infos of the `id="animatedgif"` div and by adding a `text-indent:0px` to it + by changing the `id="btn_fs"` div's css into `position: relative; top: -78px; right: 10px; text-align: right;`. But don't know how to handle the fullscreen (video not-centered and button not there - it's also not there anymore once i escaped fullscreen).

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot about the `esc` key... You need a keypress listener on the `document`. We'll deal with that later on. The FS button is now pushed to the bottom/right of your page (scroll down and right to see it at bottom)... See if the new code updates will fix the FS button's position. **PS:** Video width is set to 100% so it fits within a container. Your container is `animatedgif` and where it goes in position or size, the Image and Video tags inside the container Div will also re-position or resize.

Comment: Thanks ! It works now like a charm for both normal and fullscreen (see the last video added to the test page). The weird thing is that on my Chrome, the video restarts from the start when you click on fullscreen (and not from where it was on the page), while this problem isn't there on firefox. And there is the fullscreen video being not vertically centered (didn't find away to copy/past the bunch of code which does that on the original player). Do you know if both those things are fixable?

Comment: Ok, I realize the fact in restart from the start of the video in Chrome when in fullscreen, is because it displays in fullscreen the video of the first occurence of the code used in the page. I changed the video of the third example to show more easily (if you fullscreen in chrome the last/fourth video, you see appear in fullscreen the previous/third video).

Comment: **(1)** The problem is that there's multiple containers all using the same **id** name. See how many `<div id="animatedgif"` are in there? That confuses the computer (about which one you mean when using `getElementById` etc)... Either remove the other Divs and keep the most recent test, or give them different id names.. **(2)** About positioning video in fullscreen, it can only be done with CSS **position** set to `absolute`. I suspect the `<video>` tag can be positioned in relation to the parent (the Div) by giving the Div a `relative` setting and then set `absolute` for the video.

Comment: PS: The question was how to autoplay video inside a WordPress article in Chrome. If the advice in my Answer solves that issue then please mark my Answer as correct so others can see that it has a possible solution for them too. You can upvote too if it was useful in some way. We can worry about CSS positions after the main issue (Chrome/Firefox playback) is solved.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I always forget to mark the answers are correct or upvote... The article using those video with have a lot of them (around 10), so different ID name would be the solution, but is there a way to change the javascript itself without just copy/pasting it with a different ID name each time? (tell me when you're fed up to work on this, I am well aware I have already taken a lot of your time - and the fact I'm newbie in code doesn't help).

Comment: Thanks for accepting. I've upvoted yours as useful too since you're actively trying to fix the problem. My area of expertise is the video part. I'm learning from your CSS. **(1)** About the **id** yeah you can use function parameters, so each Div's `onclick` gives it's own unique id to the one fullscreen function. **(2)** I might have a solution for aligning the video in full screen. Will show you both codes in the morning (as I cannot promise today)

Comment: Thanks, but don't worry there is not rush! I didn't understand your first point (sorry, style newbie): where do I put the different ID variation? Somewhere on the page code, in the javascript code? If it's the javascript, it's by copy/pasting the whole code each time and changing the ID in it (which could take a lot of place)? I tried to just change the onclick (`onclick="go_FullScreen(1)"` / `onclick="go_FullScreen(2)"`) on the page, but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Hi. To have multiple videos you just create multiple copies of the "animatedGIF" Div. You've done that part already so next is... You can take advantage of the `this` **keyword**.  This means you just use `onclick="go_FullScreen( this )"` in the HTML setup of each div. Now in JS you update the "go_Fullscreen" function to look like `function go_FullScreen( myInput )`. Now the `this` in HTML setup becomes a JS reference called `myInput` so to access or check what element the computer sees as "myInput" you can do `myInput.parentNode.id` to get the div name that holds your specific clicked button.

Comment: PS: In the HTML part you still need unique ID names for the div, like `id="vid1"` and  `id="vid2"` ... Anyways test this code `function go_FullScreen( myInput ) { alert("Will do Fullscreen on Div named : " + myInput.parentNode.id); return; }` ..so in the code you have on WP, just add `myInput` part in function setup, then put those two lines as first part of function. The `return` makes the function exit (so you can test click another Div, etc). If you want to test further (no return) then also add `myVideoGIF = document.getElementById( myInput.parentNode.id );` to update code references.

Comment: Hello! Thanks, but at this point, I'm too newbie and I am really totally lost... I don't understand javascript at all, and despite my tries, I don't understand exactly what must change or be left behind in the javascript code. It's maybe too much to ask, but would it possible to put the all updated javascript code in your answer (or in jsfiddle) for me to be sure what to change in it? Also, I'm not sure to understand: the `id="vid1"` must replace  `id="animatedgif"`? It breaks the function, so I think it's not that, but don't know where to put it.

Comment: Ok. Just wait for an update to the code. I've had a chance to test more things and finally solved the vertical align issue. No worries about being a Javascript newbie. I'll add some code comments in there so you understand...

Comment: Well, weirdly the last message disappeared: I was just saying thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries. My delay was that everything was okay and was going to type an answer, then I tested with 2 videos and it broke apart (one video was ok on exiting FS but the other kept changing alignment so no Answer till I have time to solve it). See if the new update is closer to what you want. Study the code (_eg:_ why is it using **.clientHeight** instead of **.height** or **.offsetHeight** or **.scrollHeight**?). You'll know the why by experimenting / changing things within the code. Use **console.log** to check numbers

Comment: **PS**: Also other things to change include: position of the FS button. See how it uses (in Styles setup) a `top: 86%; left: 90%;`? Those percentages are assigned from Parent size. Sometimes a widescreen video may be smaller (or thinner) vertically than the Div, so where the FS icon is shown at 90% but the actual picture height is at 80% inside the Parent div, then you might want to use numbers for video's height instead of div's height (to decide position of of fullscreen icon).

Comment: **PPS:** To **console.log** any checks... For now I recommend you put a click listener (and related function) maybe on some Parent div and have it detect the height of its **children[0]**... The numbers change between FS mode and Normal mode. Check things/numbers constantly and make decisions based on what the computer is seeing. You might have to ask a new question if stuck with that part (checking height of video to align button) or else just hire a professional coder to finalize it for you.

Comment: Hello! It works now well for the function itself (the right video in fullscreen, even if there are two of it in the page), as you can see on the test page. There is an extra `</p>` in both video html codes, i suppressed it for now, not knowing if it was normal... The result have some issues: no way for the windows to be 100% of the article width, and the fullscreen button is not always on the same place depending of the height of the video.

Comment: But I'm totally unaware on how to use "console.log" or a "click listener" (don't know what it is), nor have I enough knowledge to understand what differentiate .clientHeight / .height / .offsetHeight / .scrollHeight into a javascript code. Really, Javascript is a totally foreign language to me, I would have to learn from zero (which I simply can't do this month)... Once again, really, don't feel obliged to continue investigating this if it's too much work, because I really am not able to participate and try things more into this than inside the html/css code. Anyway, once again, thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know about any extra `<p>` tags. As long as they are not inside the "AnimatedGIF" div then they won't affect the video controls. **(1)** For stretching the video container to be 100% you could change the AnimatedGIF div's width (in Styles) from `width: 640px;` into `width: 100%;` and be finished. **(2)** About FS alignment, yes that needs JS since you need to extract height of video tag. Options are: You could edit all videos at same resolution (eg:_ your video GIF means a 640x480 video). Or you could give the div a `background-color` in styles setting.

Comment: **(3)** CSS `<style>` is loaded before `<body>` which has the video tags. There is no way for CSS to know any video size. That's why JS steps in (it detect when things are loaded or usable etc)... Anyways not sure how you ended up with a plan for making a website with videos but yet not having some JS experience. To add a click listener to a tag its enough to just add `onclick="someFunction()"` in tag setup, where the `someFunction` is the name of function you want to run (it exists inside the `<script>` tag).... As you say though no point explaining further.