# Video (MUX) fullscreen on iOS doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, next.js, video

i have embedded a video through mux service on a react/next.js stackflow:

```
  const muxPlayerRef = useRef<any | null>(null)


 const startVideo = () => {
if (muxPlayerRef.current) {
  muxPlayerRef.current.play()
  muxPlayerRef.current.requestFullscreen()
}
}


   <MuxPlayer
    ref={muxPlayerRef}
    playbackId={isMobile ? 'B02VkHGciyg01SX5cYcck' : 'fqrRcy8X7fl8ZW7llg7g02y'}
    streamType="on-demand"
  />
```

everything is working fine on desktop (safari, firefox etc.) but on safari iOS/iPhone the video starts playing but I got the following error message and it doesn't open it on fullscreen:

```
 TypeError: r.current.requestFullscreen is not a function. (In 'r.current.requestFullscreen()', 'r.current.requestFullscreen' is undefined)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is this [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75239922/2057709) useful to solving your problem?