# How to add video controls over the video

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, html5-video

I have a video with my custom controls.

I need to make the controls available at any time., but when I open fullscreen version of the video, the controls hide.

Here is my code:

```js
var video = document.querySelector(".video");
var toggleButton = document.querySelector(".toggleButton");
var toggleButtonId = document.getElementById("toggleButton");
var progress = document.querySelector(".progress");
var progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress__filled");
var progressId = document.getElementById('progressId');
var volumeBar = document.getElementById('volume-bar');
function togglePlay() {
 if (video.paused || video.ended) {
    video.play();
  } else {
    video.pause();
 }
}
function updateToggleButton() {
  toggleButtonId.innerHTML = video.paused ? "►" : "❚❚";
}

function handleProgress() {
  const progressPercentage = (video.currentTime / video.duration) * 100;
  progressBar.style.flexBasis = `${progressPercentage}%`;
}

function scrub(e) {
  const scrubTime = (e.offsetX / progress.offsetWidth) * video.duration;
  video.currentTime = scrubTime;
}
volumeBar.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
    video.volume = evt.target.value;
});
video.addEventListener("click", togglePlay);
video.addEventListener("play", updateToggleButton);
video.addEventListener("pause", updateToggleButton);

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", handleProgress);
progressId.addEventListener("click", scrub);
var mousedown = false;
progressId.addEventListener("mousedown", () => (mousedown = true));
progressId.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => mousedown && scrub(e));
progressId.addEventListener("mouseup", () => (mousedown = false));
function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (video.requestFullscreen) {
      if (document.fullScreenElement) {
          document.cancelFullScreen();
      } else {
          video.requestFullscreen();
      }
  }
  else if (video.msRequestFullscreen) {
      if (document.msFullscreenElement) {
          document.msExitFullscreen();
      } else {
          video.msRequestFullscreen();
      }
  }
  else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      if (document.mozFullScreenElement) {
          document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else {
          video.mozRequestFullScreen();
      }
  }
  else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      if (document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
          document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
      } else {
          video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      }
  }
  else {
      alert("Pantalla completa no esta soportada");
  }
}
```

```html
<html data-bs-theme="dark" >
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>
  <div>
<video id="video" class="video w-100">
<source src="https://test.loro.ec/www/t/test.loro.ec/images/articles_blocks/608.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
  <div class="controls position-relative" style="top: -50px;margin-left: 8px;">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-1">
      <button class="controls__button toggleButton btn" id="toggleButton" title="Toggle Play" onclick="togglePlay()">►</button>
      </div>
      <div class="progress col-5 p-0" id="progressId">
      <div class="progress__filled" style="background: rebeccapurple;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
     <i class="bi bi-volume-up"></i> 
     <input class="form-range" style="width: 80%;" type="range" id="volume-bar" title="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
     </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <button class="btn" onclick="toggleFullScreen()"><i class="bi bi-arrows-fullscreen"></i></button>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div></div>
</html>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/alexvambato/pen/QWYGeGV

I have implemented external library (bootstrap)

I need any answer without the use of jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your video player content (icon, video object etc) into one `<div>`,
 then **fullscreen that specific div element**. Also this [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75239922/2057709) might help you.

**Solution:**
In the example code below, a new div with id of `container_vid` is created to contain the `<video>` tag together with its related UI elements.

**(1)** Update your JavaScript code:

In your first line (about `var video` etc...) update it to access "container" div as a variable.

```
var container_vid = document.getElementById("vid_container");
var video = document.querySelector(".video");
//etc... etc... rest of JS code
```

Then update your function `toggleFullScreen()` as:

```
function toggleFullScreen() 
{
  if (container_vid.requestFullscreen) 
  {
      if (document.fullScreenElement) { document.cancelFullScreen(); } 
      else { container_vid.requestFullscreen(); }
  }
  else if (container_vid.msRequestFullscreen) 
  {
      if (document.msFullscreenElement) { document.msExitFullscreen(); } 
      else { container_vid.msRequestFullscreen(); }
  }
  else if (container_vid.mozRequestFullScreen) 
  {
      if (document.mozFullScreenElement) { document.mozCancelFullScreen(); } 
      else { container_vid.mozRequestFullScreen(); }
  }
  else if (container_vid.webkitRequestFullscreen) 
  {
      if (document.webkitFullscreenElement) { document.webkitCancelFullScreen(); } 
      else { container_vid.webkitRequestFullscreen(); }
  }
  else { alert("Pantalla completa no esta soportada"); }
}
```

**(2)** Update the HTML code to include a container `<div>` :

```
<html data-bs-theme="dark" >
<head>
</head>
<div>

<div id="vid_container" > <!--open new div for containing video UI -->

<video id="video" class="video w-100">
<source src="https://test.loro.ec/www/t/test.loro.ec/images/articles_blocks/608.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div class="controls position-relative" style="top: -50px;margin-left: 8px;">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-1">
  <button class="controls__button toggleButton btn" id="toggleButton" title="Toggle Play" onclick="togglePlay()">►</button>
  </div>
  <div class="progress col-5 p-0" id="progressId">
  <div class="progress__filled" style="background: rebeccapurple;"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
 <i class="bi bi-volume-up"></i> 
 <input class="form-range" style="width: 80%;" type="range" id="volume-bar" title="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
 </div>
<div class="col-1">
<button class="btn" onclick="toggleFullScreen()"><i class="bi bi-arrows-fullscreen"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>  <!-- close div for containing video UI -->

</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t have your own controls in full screen. Full screen videos are controlled by the operating system, not by the web browser. If you need to retain your own controls, don’t provide a full screen option. You could instead provide a "full page" option which displays your video in a full-width overlay above your webpage.

Comment: Ok, but youtube have a full screen option with controls. Do you know how do as in youtube?

Comment: The possible solution will be create a script to do all web page in full screen and then in this function create full page video