# How can I move the video playback controls outside the video player in HTML?

Tags: html5-video

I am working on a small piece of code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HTML5 Video Player</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video controls preload="metadata" muted playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="">
        <source src="example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <!-- You can add additional source elements for different video formats (e.g., WebM, Ogg) -->
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to adjust the positioning of seek bar in HTML 5 <video> tag. can anyone explain is it possible to do?

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: _"I want to adjust the positioning of the seek bar in an HTML5 `<video>` tag."_ That depends on your browser type (_eg:_ webkit vs gecko, etc). You need to be using a CSS `<style>` tag to define the position of any screen element (_eg:_ adjust CSS `top` and `left` settings). Here is [**an example code**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75040102/2057709) (see _"Old Answer"_ section) where some controls are turned off (via CSS option `display` with a setting of `none`). Does it work in your browser? What is the name of your browser? These things need to be known before we can help you with an Answer